# WWW::Curl installation via CPAN fails with multiple errors

Tags: perl, curl, cpan

I tried to install WWW::Curl like `perl -MCPAN -e 'install WWW::Curl'`.
During `Curl.xs` build I get the following errors:

> cc -c  -I/usr/local/include  -DHAS_FPSETMASK -DHAS_FLOATINGPOINT_H
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing    -DVERSION=\"4.17\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"4.17\" -DPIC -fPIC "-I/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24/mach/CORE"   Curl.c In file included from Curl.xs:574:
>
> ./curlopt-constants.c:19:58: error:
>
> non-void function 'constant' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
>               if (strEQ(name, "DID_MEMORY_FUNC_TYPEDEFS")) return CURL_DID_MEMORY_FUNC_TYPEDEFS;
>
> ./curlopt-constants.c:136:49: error: use of undeclared identifier
>
> 'CURL_STRICTER'
>               if (strEQ(name, "STRICTER")) return CURL_STRICTER;

And a lot of warnings after that.

Is there anything I'm missing?

I tried to build `WWW::Curl` with perl 5.24.3, on FreeBSD 11.1

Comment: Check CpanTesters to see if that combo has been built successfully: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=WWW-Curl+4.17    Do you have libcurl already installed?

Comment: I have libcurl/7.58.0 installed

Comment: Do you have the actual development headers for libcurl installed - or just the shared library? I.e. is there a 'curl.h' file in /usr/local/include/curl/ or /usr/include/curl/ ?

Comment: Of course. There is curl.h at /usr/local/include/curl and it has all the necessary definitions. I'll try to review makefile generated for WWW::Curl

Comment: What version of cc are you using?

Comment: @jjmerelo FreeBSD clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final 297347) (based on LLVM 4.0.0)

Comment: @jjmerelo the same with gcc 4.8.5 and gcc 6.4.0

Comment: `install WWW::Curl` is Perl code that uses a bareword as a string. This syntax will bite you if you ever try to install/upgrade a module that's used by `CPAN` internally. Prefer `install "WWW:::Curl"` or `install("WWW::Curl")`. Or just use the actual `cpan` script instead of an ad-hoc `perl -e ...` one-liner: `cpan WWW::Curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an open issue in [the module repository](https://github.com/szbalint/WWW--Curl/issues/16). It's not closed, but you might want to follow it since there might be a fix in the upcoming releases or in the repo itself. The fix [might be](https://github.com/szbalint/WWW--Curl/issues/16#issuecomment-222556096)

```
if ($e =~ /(OBSOLETE|^CURL_EXTERN|_LAST\z|_LASTENTRY\z|CURL_DID_MEMORY_FUNC_TYPEDEFS\z)/) {
```

in line 140 of Makefile.PL

Comment: In my case this was line 130 and the final condition looked like `if($e =~ /(OBSOLETE|^CURL_EXTERN|_LAST\z|_LASTENTRY\z|CURL_DID_MEMORY_FUNC_TYPEDEFS\z|CURL_STRICTER\z)/) {`

Anyway it worked. Thanks a lot!